# Python parse table from HTML using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the tables from multiple html files. Ideally, I have the rows and columns in a list, so I can process it further. I am new to BeautifulSoup, but I cannot get it working. I think the main problem occurs when the function returns None, so it cannot be processed further. I tried if statements but this did not help. My code as it is right now:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
table_dict = {}
for filename, text in tqdm(lowercase_dict.items()):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table')
    table_body = table.find('tbody')
    if table_body is not None:
        tables = table_body

    rows = tables.find_all('tr')
    for row in rows:
        cols = row.find_all('td')
        cols = [ele.text.strip() for ele in cols]
        data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele])

    table_dict[filename] = cols
```

````
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-304-14ade2e7b2ac> in <module>()
      7         tables = table_body
      8 
----> 9     rows = tables.find_all('tr')
     10     for row in rows:
     11         cols = row.find_all('td')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_all'

```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error message, the problem is that the variable *tables* is a string.  Try it without using 'tbody'.

```
for filename, text in tqdm(lowercase_dict.items()):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, "lxml")
    table = soup.find('table')
    rows = table.find_all('tr')
```